# Action of $T_p$ on automorphic forms, and error in Gelbart's "Automorphic forms on adele groups"?

Tags: algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, adeles

Let $f\in\mathcal{S}_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$ be a cuspidal modular form, and $\phi_f\in\mathcal{A}_0(\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}),\omega)$ be its corresponding cuspidal automorphic form, where $\omega$ is the adelization of $\chi$. In particular, $\phi_f$ is given by the following formula:
$$ \phi_f(g)=(\det h)^{k/2}j(h,i)^{-k}f(h(i))\omega(u) $$
where $\gamma\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$, $h\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})^+$, $u\in U_0(N)$ so that $g=\gamma hu$ by strong approximation, and where
$$ U_0(N) = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{GL}_2(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}):c\equiv0\pmod{N\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}} \right\}. $$
Let $\mathcal{H}_p$ be the space of compactly supported locally constant complex-valued functions on $G_p = \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ that forms an $\mathbb{C}$-algebra under convolution, and it is called the *local Hecke algebra* at $p$. Let $K_p = \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ be the maximal compact subgroup of $G_p$. Let $\alpha_p = \begin{pmatrix}p & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Then there is a special element of $\mathcal{H}_p$, the characteristic function of $K_p\alpha_pK_p$,

$$ T_p = \mathbb{1}_{K_p\alpha_pK_p}\in\mathcal{H}_p, $$
called the $T_p$ Hecke operator, and it acts on right $T_p$-invariant automorphic forms $\phi$ by
$$ (T_p\phi)(g) = \int_{G_p} T_p(h)\phi(gh)\ dh = \phi\left(g\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & p\end{pmatrix}\right) + \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\phi\left(g\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}\right). $$
**I want to show that**
$$ T_p\phi_f=p^{1-k/2}\phi_{T_pf}, $$
**but I am having trouble with the calculation.**

**My attempt.**

I'm following the calculation in Gelbart's *Automorphic Forms on Adele Groups*, [p. 48-49](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4PTg.jpg), but I think he makes a mistake.

Let $g=\gamma hu$ as above, and also specify the following matrices of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}) = \prod_{p\leq\infty}'\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$:
\begin{align*}
      \beta &= \left(\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\dots,\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\dots\right) \\
      \beta_\infty &= \left(\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\dots,\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\dots\right) \\
      \beta_p &= \left(\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\dots,\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\dots\right) \\
      \beta^{(p\infty)} &= \left(\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\dots,\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}p & -i \\ & 1\end{pmatrix},\dots\right)
\end{align*}
where the first entry is the $\infty$-place, i.e. $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, and where subscript $i$ includes inclusion at the $i$-th place(s), and superscript $i$ denotes exclusion at the $i$-th place(s). Let also
\begin{align*}
    \gamma' &= \gamma\beta \in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}) \\
    h' &= \beta_\infty^{-1}h \in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})^+ \\
    u' &= u(\beta^{(p\infty)})^{-1} \in U_0(N).
\end{align*}
Then Gelbart claims that
$$ g\beta_p = (\gamma hu)(\beta\beta_\infty^{-1}(\beta^{(p\infty)})^{-1}) = (\gamma\beta)(\beta_\infty^{-1}h)(u(\beta^{(p\infty)})^{-1}) = \gamma' h'u'. $$
However, I don't believe he's commuting the matrices correctly. (In particular, I don't think matrices are commuting correctly in the $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$-coordinate.) But I also don't know how to fix this.

This seems like a standard calculation, but I can't find any sources which actually do all the steps in the calculation. Most of them either refer to Gelbart, or just leaves it as an exercise. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, cross-posting is generally discouraged to save answering effort/avoid clogging up unanswered queues, but pointing out that you're doing it is certainly better.  Maybe delete one of the posts?

Comment: Anyway, I don't remember if I checked Gelbart's calculation, but it certainly is standard.  Here are some other books where I think it may be worked out.  Adelically: Knightly-Li or Miyake.  In classical language: Diamond-Shurman.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I’ll check them out. (By the way, I have deleted the other post.)

Comment: I would suggest trying to do the problem yourself rather than reading someone else's account - I find these things very forgettable having read it not done it myself. That said, here's a hint: the problem is that the $\beta_{p}(i)$ matrix doesn't necessarily satisfy $ \beta_p(i) ^{-1} K_p \beta_p(i) \subset K_p $, but maybe there exists a $j$ such that $\beta_p(j)^{-1} K_p \beta_p(i) \subset K_p $. The terms in $T_p(f) $ don't match up directly with the terms in $T_p(\phi)$, there is some permutation happening. Hope that helps.

Comment: @GeorgeR Thanks for the hint. I just did the calculation, and I was able to show that there is an open compact subgroup $H\subset K_p$ (whose image under the determinant map surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$) as well as an automorphism $\tau: [p]\to[p]$ such that $\beta_p(\tau(i))^{-1}H\beta_p(i)\subset K_p$. This is good enough for calculating the action of $T_p$, but do you know if the statement is still true if I replace $H$ with all of $K_p$?